# Installing requests security requirements, locked

Tags: python, security, pip, python-requests, pypi

I'm trying to install security fix for SSL on python:

```
#  pip -v  install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1  --timeout 10 --default-timeout=10

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyopenssl in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ndg-httpsclient in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cryptography>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cryptography>=0.7->pyopenssl)
Cleaning up...
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
"GET /pypi/pip/json HTTP/1.1" 200 50976
```

---

If I interrupt:

---

```
/pypi/pip/jsonTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 248, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 605, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 750, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 673, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 307, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 243, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 244, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 276, in set
    return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches/file_cache.py", line 99, in set
    with self.lock_class(name) as lock:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/lockfile/__init__.py", line 238, in __enter__
    self.acquire()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/lockfile/mkdirlockfile.py", line 56, in acquire
    time.sleep(wait)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

---

Any advice? I tried timeout and default-timeout after some search but they are totaly ignored I suppose.

on code I see:

```
def acquire(self, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout is not None and timeout or self.timeout
    end_time = time.time()
    if timeout is not None and timeout > 0:
        end_time += timeout

    if timeout is None:
        wait = 0.1
    else:
        wait = max(0, timeout / 10)

    while True:
        try:
            os.mkdir(self.lock_file)
        except OSError:
            err = sys.exc_info()[1]
            if err.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                # Already locked.
                if os.path.exists(self.unique_name):
                    # Already locked by me.
                    return
                if timeout is not None and time.time() > end_time:
                    if timeout > 0:
                        raise LockTimeout("Timeout waiting to acquire"
                                          " lock for %s" %
                                          self.path)
                    else:
                        # Someone else has the lock.
                        raise AlreadyLocked("%s is already locked" %
                                            self.path)
                **time.sleep(wait)**
            else:
                # Couldn't create the lock for some other reason
                raise LockFailed("failed to create %s" % self.lock_file)
        else:
            open(self.unique_name, "wb").close()
            return
```

---

How can I resolve this problem? Anybody have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if in the log displayed there is the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py",
>   line 40, in acquire
>       os.mkdir(self.lock_file) FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:
>   'c:\users\\appdata\local\pip\cache\http\f\e\d\0
>   \e\fed0ed508030b766d5b0c2792132c8bf197804464765b46b361f93a4.lock'

in the case you can try to delete the pip directory and try again